# i have a question about using pointer funtion

Tags: c, pointers

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}Point;
void Swappoint(Point*w, Point*m) {
    Point re;
    re=*w;
    *w = *m;
    *m = re;
}//@
int main(){
    Point m1 = { 1,2 };
    Point m2= { 3,4 };
    Swappoint(&m1,&m2);
    printf("%d %d %d %d", m1.a, m1.b, m2.a, m2.b);
    return 0;
}
```

at point @,this point i can't understand why pointer w can be re. re is not a pointer how can Point re can be pointer w?

Comment: If you're referring to `re=*w;` and `*m = re;`, its nothing more than assigning a de-referenced pointer resulting value to a target. That they are structs is probably what is confusing you. Rewrite the code to do the same thing with regular `int *` arguments and local `int` temp var. The code within will be *identical*.

Comment: `w` is a `Point*` so `*w` is a `Point` and `re=*w;` assigns to `re` the `Point` object that `w` points to.

Comment: In other words, (1) in `Point* w`, the `*` is used to talk about a pointer-to-Point type (that's why I like to put the `*` next to the type especially for newcomers), but (2) in `... = *w` the `*` is used to say, "Give me the value being pointed to, not the pointer" (a.k.a. "dereferencing"), and (3) in `*w = ...` the `*` is used to say, "Store it in place of the value being pointed to." Imagine the 3 cases as completely different, just using the same symbol `*`. (Actually there is a reason they share the symbol but it can be confusing for beginners.)

Comment: @AndrewCheong - that can make things less readable. Does `int* a, b, c;` declare three pointers to `int`? Of course not, `int *a, b, c;` makes that clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Agreed. But I explain it that way sometimes to teach. Once they know how it works, they can easily see themselves to a proper style. (In my case, in the company I worked for, we simply disallowed multiple declarations.)

Comment: I get you. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, That's an reason for never writing `int* a, b, c;`, not a reason for writing `int *a;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens for each line inside `Swappoint` function:

> ```
> Point re;
> ```

Create a static variiabe to hold point and call it re.

> ```
> re=*w;
> ```

Go to the address of pointer `w` and copy the values of a and b to `re`

> ```
> *w = *m;
> ```

Take the date of where m is pointing and place in where w is pointing

> ```
> *m = re;
> ```

take the data to re and put that to where m is pointing

Here, pointer m is de-referenced

So while `m` is a pointer to `Point` , `*m` is Point itself

Comment: `Point re` is _automatic_, not `static`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Swappoint(Point *w, Point *m) {
    Point re;
    re=*w;    // Dereferencing 'w' and assigning the value containing it into 're'
    *w = *m;  // Value of 'm' after dereference, is assigned to 'w'
    *m = re;  // Value of 're' is assigned to 'm'
}
```

Dereferencing a pointer variable won't give pointer as the result, it'll give some value.